# Heroku custom domain ssl name mismatch error

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I've added a custom domain (bought on GoDaddy) to my Heroku app and am on the hobby dyno. When I type in `www.example.com` everything works fine, but when I open `example.com` I get a name mismatch error.

My cname host `www` points to `example-78914389.herokudns.com` and I have forward to https://www.example.com on GoDaddy enabled.

The certificate is only valid for the following names: shortener.secureserver.net, www.shortener.secureserver.net.

Why is the certificate valid for these domains and not for my example.com?
I don't know if it matters, but I just ported the domain from zeit now to GoDaddy.

Comment: I presume you're using GoDaddy's redirect to send example.com to www.example.com. If so, that service doesn't support HTTPS. Most registrar redirect systems don't; CloudFlare and Google Domains are some of the only ones I've found that do.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm using the Forward to function in GoDaddy. Does that mean I can't get it to work at all?

Comment: Correct, at least with GoDaddy. That said, most people won't type the HTTPS in at all.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like it works now. I had set cname TTL to 600 seconds a half hour ago and when I use a private window now it does work.

Comment: You're saying `https://example.com/` works, with the S and no-www? Doesn't match my experience with GoDaddy, but perhaps they finally fixed it.

Comment: I also deleted my cache, but before that, it didn't work. I'm not sure why it works now. I don't even have to type in https it gets automatically added.

Comment: It might help if you give the actual domain name. I'm not sure we're talking about the same two things. What happens when you **do** type in the `https://example.com/`?

Comment: That's weird. I just close my private window and reopened it and now it doesn't work anymore. https://example.com gives me a warning again and www.example.com just uses http and https://www.example.com works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
I transferred my domain from GoDaddy to namecheap, then made an ALIAS record. I've also added `example.com` to my app in Heroku. I now have `www.example.com` and `example.com` added and both domains work.

If you have the same issue, check this out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain